# How to set up a new Aptana Studio 3 project using Git and online repository

Tags: git, aptana3

I'm trying to set up a project for a new web site in Aptana Studio 3 using Git so others can work on the project as well.

My plan is to work on/test the project locally using Aptana and my WAMP server. I would then commit it to an online repository (which currently doesn't exist, so that would have to be created in the process) in the domain for which the web site is being built.

I've been searching, researching, and reading for an hour and a half and I've gotten nowhere.

I'm pretty familiar with Aptana, but I've never used Git before.

How do I accomplish this? (Step-by-step instructions will be **greatly** appreciated!)

Comment: No replies? C'mon, guys! I need some help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to request that this question be closed by someone (I don't have enough points to close it).

Obviously no one has been willing and/or able to answer it, and the question is no longer relevant to **my** needs, as I have figured out how to install Subversion on my shared hosting account. So I will be using that versioning software instead.